# Error installing PyQt 5.4.2: sip api reference

Tags: qt5, ubuntu-14.04, pyqt5, python-3.4, python-sip

I need help trying to figure out why I am having this error:

```
[everything fine until here...]
In file included from sipQtCoreQTimeZoneOffsetData.cpp:24:0:
/home/hugo/Desktop/my_pyqt_examples/PyQt-gpl-5.4.2/QtCore/sipQtCoreQTimeZoneOffsetData.cpp: In function ‘PyObject* varget_QTimeZone_OffsetData_abbreviation(void*, PyObject*, PyObject*)’:
/home/hugo/Desktop/my_pyqt_examples/PyQt-gpl-5.4.2/QtCore/sipAPIQtCore.h:9581:52: error: ‘const sipAPIDef’ has no member named ‘api_get_reference’
 #define sipGetReference             sipAPI_QtCore->api_get_reference
                                                    ^
/home/hugo/Desktop/my_pyqt_examples/PyQt-gpl-5.4.2/QtCore/sipQtCoreQTimeZoneOffsetData.cpp:128:13: note: in expansion of macro ‘sipGetReference’
     sipPy = sipGetReference(sipPySelf, -13);
             ^
/home/hugo/Desktop/my_pyqt_examples/PyQt-gpl-5.4.2/QtCore/sipQtCoreQTimeZoneOffsetData.cpp: In function ‘PyObject* varget_QTimeZone_OffsetData_atUtc(void*, PyObject*, PyObject*)’:
/home/hugo/Desktop/my_pyqt_examples/PyQt-gpl-5.4.2/QtCore/sipAPIQtCore.h:9581:52: error: ‘const sipAPIDef’ has no member named ‘api_get_reference’
 #define sipGetReference             sipAPI_QtCore->api_get_reference
                                                    ^
/home/hugo/Desktop/my_pyqt_examples/PyQt-gpl-5.4.2/QtCore/sipQtCoreQTimeZoneOffsetData.cpp:170:13: note: in expansion of macro ‘sipGetReference’
     sipPy = sipGetReference(sipPySelf, -14);
             ^
make[1]: *** [sipQtCoreQTimeZoneOffsetData.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/hugo/Desktop/my_pyqt_examples/PyQt-gpl-5.4.2/QtCore'
make: *** [sub-QtCore-make_first-ordered] Error 2
```

I am installing PyQt 5.4 inside a virtualenv on Ubuntu 14.04. I already installed SIP (version 4.16.8, `which sip` returns the one inside the virtualenv) and it seems everything is fine during the configure run:

```
python configure.py --qmake /home/hugo/Qt/5.4/gcc_64/bin/qmake
```

outputs (among other things):

```
Qt v5.4.2 (Open Source) is being used.
The qmake executable is /home/hugo/Qt/5.4/gcc_64/bin/qmake.
Qt is built as a shared library.
SIP 4.16.8 is being used.
The sip executable is /home/hugo/Desktop/my_pyqt_examples/venv/bin/sip.
These PyQt5 modules will be built: QtCore, QtGui, QtHelp, QtMultimedia,
QtMultimediaWidgets, QtNetwork, QtOpenGL, QtPrintSupport, QtQml, QtQuick,
QtSql, QtSvg, QtTest, QtWebKit, QtWebKitWidgets, QtWidgets, QtXml,
QtXmlPatterns, QtDesigner, QtDBus, _QOpenGLFunctions_2_0,
_QOpenGLFunctions_2_1, _QOpenGLFunctions_4_1_Core, QtSensors, QtSerialPort,
QtX11Extras, QtBluetooth, QtPositioning, QtQuickWidgets, QtWebSockets, Enginio,
QtWebChannel, QtWebEngineWidgets.
The PyQt5 Python package will be installed in
/home/hugo/Desktop/my_pyqt_examples/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages
```

Tell me if more info is needed.
I also tried to install PyQt 5.2 agains the qt version of the Ubuntu repos but I got the same error. What can I do?

**EDIT:**

I overcame this problem using `sip 4.16.7` instead. But I think this is not the solution, so if anyone knows why the most recent version does not work please elaborate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into the same problem and I've fixed it by specifying the sip path before the `make` step:
`python configure.py --sip-incdir=/opt/sip-4.6.9/include/python2.7`

Comment: Cheers, mate. Setting correct `--sip-incdir` did it.

Comment: I did not test this solution myself, but since @K3---rnc reports that it works, I will mark this as an answer.